# Автоматизированный скрипт

Tags: api, консоль, shell, telegram, termux

Буду краток.
Использую Termux в качестве замены Linux

Нашел на просторах интернета `"telegram-cli"` пакет.
Захотелось поэкспериментировать и зафиксировать статус, то есть "вечный онлайн".

Вопрос, как написать скрипт, который через каждые 2 минуты вводил бы команду `status_online`

Comment: Собственно в чем вопрос? Как написать скрипт? Как через `telegram-cli` ввести команду `status_online`? Как запустить скрипт каждые 2 минуты?

Comment: Да. Чтобы он автоматически это делал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда crontab.

Если предельно упрощенно: в файл `/etc/crontab` добавляете строку

`*/2 * * * * user /path/to/script`

Вместо `user` указать имя пользователя (как вариант `root`). Вместо `/path/to/script` указать имя файла (с путем) с Вашим скриптом.

Все. Ваш скрипт будет запускаться каждые 2 минуты.

Если хочется чуть посложнее, то возможны варианты.

Например, вместо `/path/to/script` можно указать сразу `telegram-cli` с нужными параметрами.

Еще варианты - сейчас не принято редактировать сам файл `/etc/crontab`. Вместо этого создается новый файл в папке `/etc/cron.d`.

Также можно воспользоваться командой `crontab -e`.

Comment: какой crontab в termux???

Comment: а что `while; do telegram-cli status_online; sleep 120; done &` уже не работает?

Comment: А в чем проблема с crontab?
https://www.google.com/search?q=termux+crontab
Там куча ссылок, например
https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/i27szk/how_do_i_crontab_on_termux/

Comment: вот по-моему единственное рабочее решение https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:Boot

Comment: sleep 120 - тоже вариант

Comment: я имел в виду тот факт, что crond в termux работает только при запущенном терминале, если его свернуть, он не работает, потому и говорю запускать через Termux:Boot или Tasker